# Adding image in place of color in android using achartengine

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to insert an image in chart in android using achartengine.
Is it possible to set image in place of color for chart in android using achartengine? I have a problem to show progress in chart.So,I decided to add image in place of color

```
int[] Mycolors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#ff9c40"),Color.parseColor("#ffc16f"),
         Color.parseColor("#34d3c4"),Color.parseColor("#a0eee8")};

String[] average = { "schedule1", "schedule2", "schedule3","schedule4"};
```